# cannot run a .svb file

Tags: windows, windows-7, wsh

I am using Windows 7 and have associated .svb files with C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe which is the Windows Script Host program

But when I click the file I get the popup "There is no script engine for file extension .svb"

I have googled it but cold find a solution

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

wscript.exe seems to be just a stub which itself calls the interpreter for Visual Basic Script, JavaScript etc. based on the file extension. You have associated the .svb extension with wscript.exe, but wscript.exe does not know what to do with it. That said, you probably have a typo there, and the file should be named .vbs (for Visual Basic Script) instead of .svb.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a VBScript file to play the sound.
2. Open Notepad and paste the following lines into it:

   ```vb
   Set oVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
   set oSpFileStream = CreateObject("SAPI.SpFileStream")
   oSpFileStream.Open "C:\Windows\Media\YourSoundHere.wav"
   oVoice.SpeakStream oSpFileStream
   oSpFileStream.Close
   ```
3. Save this file anywhere with a `.VBS` extension. For example, `LogonSound.vbs`.
4. Double-click the file you've created and ensure that it plays your sound file.

https://winaero.com/play-logon-sound-windows-10/